# How to create schema for already existing model in catalyst perl

Tags: perl, catalyst

I am working with perl Catalyst. I created Model and Schema for a database with model name `MyDBI.pm` and schema for that are created in SchemaClass/Result directory. Now I have added a new table in my database. Now I need to create a Schema for that table only. The following command I am using for creating Schema

```
perl script/my_create.pl model MyDBI DBIC::Schema 
    My::SchemaClass::Result::Tablename create=dynamic 
    components=TimeStamp 'dbi:Pg:dbname=mydb' username 123 '{ AutoCommit => 1}'
```

But it creating `MyDBI.pm` again as `MyDBI.pm.new.` So how can I create without creating that `MyDBI.pm`.

Thanks In Advance....

Answer (score 0):

As long as you edit the classes under Schema/Result/.pm classes only under the marked line, there is no problem it re-creates it? That way you know your model is always up-to-date.
The class in models (MyDBI.pm) only contains the connection info, right?

In the Schema classes, you find the line marked by something like this:

```
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:+ZwJisOqZAkKLq170l/CNA
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much more common and in my opinion much cleaner to add Schema classes not directly into Result.pm, which will get cluttered,

but to the Schema/Result/ directory, for example
..../Schema/Result/New.pm -> Schema::Result::New

Then `use base qw/DBIx::Class::Core/;` in the package and all is set to be used normally.

Catalyst will discover those and set them up for you automatically.